# Rx Android: Debounce calls to compute and return last computed value

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I am new to Rx Android. I see operators like throttle & debounce; however I am not able to figure out how to use it effectively in my scenario.

In my APP from several threads of execution update some global state and makes a request to perform costly computation. 
Computation needs to be performed on a different thread. Caller thread receives computation result using Observable.

There can be several consecutive or parallel calls to perform computation. I would like to debounce the calls to certain time duration and all the callers should receive the last computed value.

For ex. If three threads T1, T2 & T3 requests to perform computation within a period of 500ms then computation needs to be performed only once. All threads T1, T2 & T3 observing for the computing result (Observer) gets the last computed result.

Comment: Denounce and switch map?

Comment: is it something like you want to do onTextChange listener??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
BehaviorSubject<Object> b = new BehaviorSubject();
Observable<T> computationChain = 
      b
      .onSubscribe(() -> b.onNext(null))
      .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .map(dummy -> performExpensiveComputation())
      .share();

....

public Observable<T> getComputation() {
    return computationChain;
}

....

getComputationChain().subscribe(value -> doSomething(value));
```

Edit: maybe this will work better:

```
BehaviorSubject<Object> b = new BehaviorSubject();
Observable<T> computationChain = 
      b
      .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .map(dummy -> performExpensiveComputation())
      .publish();
      .onSubscribe(() -> b.onNext(null))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the line=>     .onSubscribe(() -> b.onNext(null)). Thanks.

Comment: That means, when somebody subscribes, then push the subscription event to the behaviorSubject as a token value (null), which will get ignored at the end  (in the map()).